# Attaching arrows in Gliffy Sequence Diagram

Tags: windows, software-rec, diagrams

I was using [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com) to draw a [sequence disagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) But there seems to be no way to attach a "message" arrow to either a timeline or to an activation box.

Have I missed something or is this deficiency a feature of Gliffy?

Any other online or Win32 apps that can be used for a quick one-off sequence diagram where messages can be attached to timelines, activation boxes and actors etc?

Comment: For online apps, ask on [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Gilles +1, thanks. By searching on Web-Apps for Giffy I found [Web Sequence Diagrams](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Gilles comment I found [Web Sequence Diagrams](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/) which follows the traditions of [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) but does it online.

You enter some text

```
note over A: text2
A->B: text
activate B
B-->A: text
deactivate B
note over A: text2
```

As you type, it produces a corresponding sequence diagram.

- No need to reorganise arrows manually after dragging some element around.
- No need to manually align tops of timelines

---

[LucidChart](http://www.lucidchart.com/) is another online charting tool that, like Gliffy, supports a wide variety of chart types. Like Gliffy, it is based on drag & drop but allows arrows to be attached to any part of a timeline or other object. I prefer WebSequenceDiagrams.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need diagramming, I think the netbeans plug-ins from VisualParadigm might do it for you: http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/sde/

all available as feature limited free trials(registration required).  The only thing they lack is code generation/db migration and the like.  The diagramming is all there(or was when i used it)